# Using "instead" with "but"

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following sentence is grammatically (more) correct?

> It's not your problem **but** your friend's.
>
> It's not your problem **but** your friend's **instead**.

Comment: The first is fine. I think I need more context to say whether *instead* is wrong/weird here.

Comment: @shawnt00: totally agree, 1up

Answer (score 1):

There are myriad ways in which you can phrase these and it would be grammatically correct, although awkward. Both of your examples are correct, but they  would strike me as a rather clunky way to get your meaning across.

I would suggest the following, which is based on my own experience as a native speaker. It omits both "*but*" and "*instead*" and relies on the form for emphasis.

> It's not your problem-- it's your friend's.

Depending on whether you want to emphasize the positive or negative aspect of the sentence, you can invert it, as in this example:

> That's my toothbrush-- not yours.

In most cases, you can flip it either way without issue:

> - His cat's a Burmese-- not a Turkish Van.
> - His cat's not a Turkish Van-- it's a Burmese.

This will sound more natural and idiomatic to most speakers, at least in American English. I would love to know if other users have a different opinion.

***Quick Note:***

I've used dashes here to link the clauses of each sentence. This seems correct to me because the sentences have a corrective, interruptive quality. In my experience, native speakers are not always keen on the punctuation rules with commas (,), colons (:), semi-colons (;), and dashes (--). Disagreements over proper usage can sometimes create opposing camps (e.g. the Oxford comma).

For what it's worth, I would say that you could substitute each dash (--) with a semi-colon (;) and the meaning would be largely the same, if a bit less emphatic.

Comment: I like dashes! They are simple and effective, and don't have you stumbling upon them like semicolons often do. BTW, there are two of them—[en-dash and em-dash.](https://superuser.com/questions/811318/how-to-type-en-dash-and-em-dash-in-windows-7-8)

Answer (score 0):

Neither sentence is great, but I would say that the first sounds better.  However, I would use something like this, instead:

> It's not your problem but, *rather*, your friend's.

(Note that my commas might be misplaced.)

Rather works better here stylistically than "instead".

Comment: My question is not about stylistic correctness but grammatical correctness (instead?).  :P

Comment: @7_R3X they're both fine, grammatically.

Comment: I prefer the OP's version to yours. For what it's worth, I would say: "It's not your problem, it's your friend's problem."

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct.  Adding "instead" just amplifies the contrast being made about whose problem it is.

Answer (score 0):

- "**instead**" is used to speak about something done or existing in place of another thing meant to be done or existing *(as an alternative)*.
- "**but**" as a conjunction is used in contrast to what has already been mentioned.

You can use them together when "**but**" and "**instead**" don't form the same idea in a sentence:

- You needed to go to the hospital **but instead** you went to the cinema. *(in contrast to going to the hospital as an alternative you chose to go to the cinema)*

Your sentence doesn't seem to work that pattern and it sounds a little bit odd with possession *(to me)*. However, I don't see anything ungrammatical about it.

- *It's not your problem but your friend's instead.* *(in contrast to not being your problem as an alternative it was that of your friend's)*

It would be much better to say, "*It's your friend's problem, not yours.*".